# Redis PUB/SUB: how to ignore own messages?

Tags: redis, publish-subscribe

The idea is: 
I have N WCF services which connected and subscribed to the same Redis message channel. These services use this channel to exchange messages to sync some caches and other data.

How each service can ignore its own messages? I.e. how to publish to all but me?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like Redis PUB/SUB doesn't support such filtration. So, the solution is to use set of individual channels for every publisher and common channel for subscription synchronization between them. Here is an [golang example of no-echo chat application](https://github.com/mangup/goredchat).